# Less memory consumption for df.loc and drop rows which specific characters in a specific column

Tags: python, pandas

i am loading a big dataframe in python, with several columns and million of rows, so for sure this is quite memory consuming. To exclude some types in a specific column I use:

```
import pandas as pd
files = glob.glob("Path/*.csv")
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t', encoding='unicode_escape') for f in files]
df = pd.concat(dfs,ignore_index=True)
df = df.loc[~df['Type'].isin('A', 'B',...,'F')]
```

What is a better way to exclude the specific types/characters to drop the rows which have this character inside? As this keeps on crashing.

Comment: You mean data types (e.g. `int`, `str`, `bool`)?

Comment: see edit, I mean to exclude the rows which this character, sorry original post was missleading

Answer (score 1):

You can deal with the memory issues using `dask`

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = dd.read_csv('file.csv')
df = df.loc[~df.Type.isin(['A', 'B',...,'F'])]
df = df.compute() # this will give back the pandas dataframe
```

This will silently carryout operations chunk-wise in the background.

Comment: is it possible to give it back to a pd.format afterwards? and can i use dask in combination with glob? As I am loading the dataframe with glob before

Comment: yes, to both. as `df` returned by `compute()` is a pandas dataframe.

Comment: If it helped, please accept as final answer :). Thanks a a lot.

Comment: the error i get with the command: compute is: ValueError: Mismatched dtypes found in `pd.read_csv`/`pd.read_table`.

Comment: could you please modify `dd.read_csv('file.csv', ..., dtype={'Type': 'object'})`